# Is Crypto-Browserify and Browserify-Zib necessary when Bunlding with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I used browserify to bundle my code, and it works fine. But the bundle size is very large. I used [disc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/disc) to check the bundle size and found that Crypto-Browserify and Browserify-Zib takes up almost half of the size. I'm pretty sure I did not require them in my code, and here is my package.json, which doesn't look like they use the two libraries too. Any idea?

```
"devDependencies": {
  "bower-files": "^3.11.3",
  "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
  "browserify": "^13.0.0",
  "browserify-shim": "^3.8.12",
  "clamp-js": "^0.7.0",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
  "gulp-eslint": "^1.1.1",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.3",
  "gulp-rev": "^6.0.1",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
  "gulp-scss-lint": "^0.3.9",
  "gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
  "gulp-tmod": "^1.0.3",
  "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
  "jquery": "^2.2.0",
  "jquery-lazyload": "^1.9.7",
  "jquery-qrcode": "^1.0.0",
  "moment": "^2.11.1",
  "raven": "^0.10.0",
  "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
  "zeptojs": "^1.1.4"
},
```